# How to change sound output to a earphone not to a hdmi?

Tags: macos

I am using Mac OS X 10.11.2. Recently I connected it to another monitor using HDMI. Whenever I turn on my mac, it sounds out to the monitor. How can I fix it sounding out to a earphone? I know where I set the audio output in mac preference. But even if I choose the earphone output, it doesn't work at all. I want to know the permanent way to fix the output to the earphone.

Answer (score 0):

`System Preferences > Sound > Output` is probably what you're looking for. Pretty sure the device you select here becomes default. You can always check the `Show volume in menu bar` to change it quickly.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. I know the menu and already tried it. But, Is there a button to make it default? I can't find. And If I check Show volumn in menu bar, it just can display the volume control button.